# Find a number t such that the vectors $u = (2\cos t, 4)$ and $v = (10,3)$ are perpendicular

Tags: vectors

> Find a number $t$ such that the vectors $u = (2\cos t, 4)$ and $v = (10,3)$ are perpendicular.

I'm very bad at vectors. I need to solve for t. I don't know where to begin. Help please

Comment: make the dot product $\vec u \cdot \vec v=20 \cos t +12 = 0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First recall the definition of when two vectors $u$ and $v$ are perpendicular: It happens exactly when their dot product is $0$: $u\cdot v = 0$.

So you just need to find the dot product of your two vectors and set it equal to $0$:

$$u\cdot v = (2\cos t,4)\cdot (10,3) = 20\cos t + 12 = 0.$$

Ok, so $20\cos t + 12 = 0$. Now the vector part is over, and you need to figure out what values of $t$ makes this equation true.

Answer (score 0):

When two vectors are perpendicular, it means their dot product vanishes.  Hence:

$(2 \cos (t), 4)\cdot (10, 3) = 0$

or

$20 \cos (t) + 12 = 0$.

$\cos (t) = {-12 \over 20} = -.6$.

Thus $t = \cos^{-1} (-.6)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Two non-zero vectors are perpendicular if and only if their dot-product is zero.  In this case, we want $t$ to be such that
$$
(2\cos t)(10) + (4)(3) = 0
$$

Answer (score 0):

Two vectors , $A$ and $B$ , are perpendicular if $A \cdot B = 0$.

Thus, we can compute the product $A \cdot B$;

$A \cdot B = (2cost,4) \cdot (10,3) = 20cost + 12$

Since we demand that $A$ and $B$ be perpendicular, $20cost + 12 = 0$;

Thus $20cost = -12 \implies cost = -\frac{3}{5} \implies t = cos^{-1}(-\frac{3}{5} )$ , and we are done.